# Max heap implementation in Kotlin

Tags: heap, kotlin

I wrote this class a while ago to learn Kotlin and heaps, so any tips (on either my code style or my heap algorithm) would be appreciated!

```
class MaxHeap<T : Comparable<T>>() {
    private val items: MutableList<T?> = mutableListOf()
    var size: Int = 0
        private set

    fun push(item: T) {
        set(size++, item)
        siftUp(size - 1)
    }

    fun peek() = get(0)

    fun pop(): T? {
        // If there are no items in the heap, null is returned
        if (size == 0) {
            return null
        }

        // Get the max item, replace it with the last item in the heap,
        // then sift it down until the heap property is restored
        val max = peek()
        set(0, get(--size))
        items.removeAt(size) // Remove original reference to the last item
        siftDown(0)
        return max
    }

    private fun siftUp(i: Int) {
        assert(i >= 0 && i < size)

        // The root node has no parent, so we cannot sift up any more
        if (i == 0) {
            return
        }

        // If the current item is larger than the parent, swap them and
        // then repeat on the item, which is now in the parent position
        val iParent = parentIndex(i)
        if (get(i)!! > get(iParent)!!) {
            swap(i, iParent)
            siftUp(iParent)
        }
    }

    private fun siftDown(i: Int) {
        assert(i >= 0 && i < size)

        // Cannot sift down leaf nodes
        if (i >= size / 2) {
            return
        }

        // Find the larger child value.
        // Left child is guaranteed to exist because this is not a leaf node,
        // and because we add items to the heap by appending them to the end,
        // the left mode must be filled before the right node.
        val iLeft = leftChildIndex(i)
        val iRight = rightChildIndex(i)
        var iLargerChild = iLeft
        if (iRight < size && get(iLeft)!! < get(iRight)!!) {
            iLargerChild = iRight
        }

        // If this item is less than the larger child, sift it down
        if (get(i)!! < get(iLargerChild)!!) {
            swap(i, iLargerChild)
            siftDown(iLargerChild)
        }
    }

    private fun set(i: Int, value: T?) {
        if (i < items.size) {
            items[i] = value
        } else {
            items.add(value)
        }
    }

    private fun get(i: Int): T? {
        if (i < items.size) {
            return items[i]
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    private fun swap(i: Int, j: Int) {
        val temp = items[i]
        items[i] = items[j]
        items[j] = temp
    }

    private fun parentIndex(i: Int) = (i - 1) / 2
    private fun leftChildIndex(i: Int) = i * 2 + 1
    private fun rightChildIndex(i: Int) = i * 2 + 2
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `private val items: MutableList<T?> = mutableListOf()` can be written more succinctly as `private val items = mutableListOf<T?>()` (the type is inferred and then no longer repeated (mostly) in an explicit type definition and the factory method call).
2. `size` can be backed by `items.size`:

   ```
   val size: Int
       get() = items.size

   fun push(item: T) {
       set(size + 1, item)
       siftUp(size - 1)
   }

   ...

   fun pop(): T? {
       ...
       set(0, get(size - 1))
       items.removeAt(items.lastIndex) // Remove original reference to the last item
       ...
   }
   ```
3. `siftDown` throws an `AssertionError` assertion when `size == 0`.
4. [`push`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#push-E-) and [`pop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#pop--) have different meanings in the [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) associated with using a [java.util.Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) as a stack. You might instead use the same verbs as [java.util.PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) (namely [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add-E-) and [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#remove--)) which can be used as a max heap:

   ```
   fun <T : Comparable<T>> maxHeap() = PriorityQueue<T>(Comparator.reverseOrder<T>())
   ```

Comment: Hmm, under what conditions can `i == size` be true?

Comment: @AndrewSun I suggest creating some unit tests. :-) That is how I caught it although after inspecting the code closer my suggested fix was probably not the best solution. As such, I've updated my #3 to simply state the problem. The best fix might be to only call `siftDown` if `size > 1`. An alternative would be to move the assertion to after the `i >= size / 2` check. I'm sure there are other ways to fix it as well.

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem, thanks. I actually did have some tests (including removing all items from the heap), I think what happened is that assertions weren't even enabled :-p I agree that not calling `siftDown` when the heap is empty would be the best solution, so the assertion would still work in all other cases.

Comment: @AndrewSun Awesome. In the future, you might even include your tests in the code review. I personally find no better documentation for main code than test code.

Answer (score 7):

This looks nice, though I don't actually know [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin).

One suggestion I'd make is that when you have multiple relational conditions in a statement like this:

> ```
> assert(i >= 0 && i < size)
> ```

It's slightly more readable if you arrange the terms in increasing order of their values, like this:

```
assert(0 <= i && i < size)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd introduce variables instead of comments. For example:

```
// If this item is less than the larger child, sift it down
    if (get(i)!! < get(iLargerChild)!!) {
```

can be rewritten as

```
var lessThanLargerChild : Boolean = get(i)!! < get(iLargerChild)!!
if (lessThanLargerChild) {
```

I'm not sure if this is correct Kotlin expression, I don't know the language but I hope you catched the idea.